# Containement of $\sigma$-algebras implies containement of sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Notation:**
If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, $\sigma(X)$ and, $\sigma(Y)$ are the $\sigma$-algebras generated by those sets respectively and $L^0(\sigma(X))$ and,$L^0(\sigma(Y))$ are the sets of measurable functions with respect to the $\sigma$-algebras generated by $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

---

Suppose I know that $L^0(\sigma(X))\subset L^0(\sigma(Y))$ then can I conclude that $X\subseteq Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A\in \sigma (X)$, then the characteristic function of $A$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable  and based on the assumption, is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, which implies $A\in \sigma(Y)$. So $\sigma(X)\subseteq \sigma(Y)$. However nothing can be said about $X$ and $Y$. For instance consider $X=\{\emptyset, A,\Omega\}$ and $Y=\{\emptyset, A^c,\Omega\}$. They both generate $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Y)$ but neither $X\subseteq Y$ not $Y\subseteq X$.

Comment: If x and y are functions does the same still hold true?

Comment: Is there any such conlusion i can draw based on my knowledge of the sigma-fields?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are already $\sigma-$algebra, which is the case for functions, then you can say $X\subseteq Y$. But otherwise I am unaware of general conditions for $X\subseteq Y$.

Comment: So just to clarify (just to be certain) if $f$ is a function and $X$ is the pull-back of the Borel-sigma algebra and $Y$ is the sigma algebra generated by a collection of functions (in the same way as X) then it is true?

Comment: It seems to me yes. If you have $L^0(\sigma(X))\subset L^0(\sigma(Y))$ the above argument should naturally lead to it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot Arash!